# Dynamics CRM Web API error: The type 'BadAmbiguousElementBinding:.' does not inherit from and is not a base type of 'BadAmbiguousElementBinding'

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

We have a Service Fabric Microservices project, which is communicating with Dynamics CRM 2016 (on-premises) through Web API calls. Version v8.2 is used. Everything works fine, but sometimes randomly we recieve the following error response from CRM:

```
"message": "The type 'BadAmbiguousElementBinding:.' does not inherit from and is not a 
base type of 'BadAmbiguousElementBinding:.'. The type of 'KeySegments' must be related
to the Type of the EntitySet."
```

Early this morning within an 1 hour timeframe all of the requests going to the CRM were failing with this error message and only after we restarted the CRM the issue went away.

What could be the reason? Any input is appreciated.